# User profile looks like a blockquote

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design

For example, from my profile:

[image: profile]

Profiles should not look like blockquotes. Furtermore, they should have a white background if possible (because people do embed images in them).

Answer (score -1):

By design.

Context clearly indicates it is not a block quote.

People take photos on a myriad of backgrounds. There is no right or wrong background color for photographs to appear on.